# Высчитать ширину блока и присвоить атрибут JS

Tags: javascript, html, width

Добрый день.

Есть вот такая верстка: http://demo.interface.club/limitless/layout_2/LTR/default/layout_footer_fixed.html

1. на странице есть блок div c классом content-wrapper, его ширина резиновая.
2. так же есть div с классом navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom

Задача:

мне нужно с помощью JS вычислить ширину экрана в пискелях, потом вычислить разницу ширины экрана и content-wrapper, тоже в пикселях. а потом полученную цифру присвоить диву c классом navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom в виде атрибута style="left: X px;" где X наше полученное число.

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: Код нужно в вопрос вставить. Так же возможно вам стоит описать что вы хотите получить, возможно есть более просто решение.

Comment: Что же в моем вопросе не понятного?

Comment: Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?
 - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/Мой-сайт-проект-не-работает-Можно-я-просто-дам-на-него-ссылку